# Understanding algebra of random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

This might be a very basic level question. I am dealing with independent and identically distributed (i.i.d) random variables, but got stuck in the following step:

$$P = A \underset{1\leq n\leq N}{\operatorname{max}} |X_n|^2 \tag 1$$

where $X$ is some random variable, $A$ is some constant. Also, the PDF of |X| is know and for simplicity I denote it by $f_X(x)$.

My query is, can we write eq.(1) as

$$P = A \{[f_X(x)]^2\}^N \tag 2$$

I mean to say can we square the PDF as done in eq. (2).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In (1) you define a random variable $P$, but (2) does not quite make sense to me. Are you trying to compute the PDF of $P$?

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response. Yes, my intention is to compute PDF of $P$.

Comment: The usual trick when dealing with the maximum of i.i.d. random variables is to first compute the CDF. Note that $\max_{1\leq n\leq N}|X_n|^2\leq x$ if and only if $|X_n|^2\leq x$ for all $1\leq n\leq N$. Using this you should be able to show that $F_P(x):=\mathbb{P}(P\leq x)=F_{|X|}(\sqrt{x/A})^N$. Then recall that the PDF can be obtained by differentiating the CDF.

Comment: Ok sir. Got your point. Can you pls tell whether $N$ is to the power of CDF of $X$ i.e., $(F_X(\sqrt{\frac{x}{A}}))^N$ or $F_X(\sqrt{\frac{x}{A}})^N$

Comment: Okay, I see that might have been unclear. I mean $(F_{|X|}(\sqrt{x/A}))^N$. This should also be clear to you when you do the computation leading to this identity.

Comment: Ok sir. Got it.